# Ineffectivness of constant in Siegel's theorem

Tags: analytic-number-theory, computability

I have a question, the following theorem of Siegel says that the constant is ineffective,i.e. not effectively computable, but I do not understand why it is actually not computable and how to prove something like that, it seems to me that in the proof they didn't proved that is ineffective.

Theorem: Let $ \chi $ be any real primitive Dirichlet character $ \mod q $, then for every $ \epsilon > 0 $
$$ L(1,\chi) > \frac{c(\epsilon)}{q^{\epsilon}} $$

where $ c(\epsilon)$ is an ineffective constant.

The proof is very short and can be found here: https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.71.4.1055

Comment: The goal is not to prove the constant is ineffective. It's just that the proof method is not strong enough to offer an effective method to calculate the constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a detail that commonly puzzles people at first. Look at the paragraph following the statement of Lemma 1:

- This must be true since if there are no real zeros in $[1-\varepsilon,1]$
  for any $L(s,\chi)$ then $f(\beta)<0$ if $1-\varepsilon<\beta< 1$, since $\xi(\beta)< 0$. On the other hand, if such real zeros do exist, let $\beta$ be such a zero and $\chi_1$ the corresponding character so that $f(\beta)= 0$ independent of $\chi_2$.

Note that this is a proof in two cases that asserts the existence of a real number $\beta$ with particular properties. Could you actually use this proof to produce an explicit such real number $\beta$? Well, no, not with our current knowledge—you would first need to know whether there exists a $\chi$ such that $L(s,\chi)$ had a zero in the interval $[1-\varepsilon,1]$, because the second case defines $\beta$ in terms of that zero. That's why this proof is ineffective—we don't know which construction of the real number $\beta$ we must use.

This already illustrates the underlying idea of ineffective proofs, but to your exact question, the constant $c(\varepsilon)$ in the main theorem is constructed out of this $\beta$, which makes it ineffective as well.

Comment: So if in the future we will know that there is no such zero for any $L$ then the constant will become effective?

Comment: I believe so, because then the "zero-free region" is truly free of zeros and thus the situation becomes analogous to the classical contour-integral proofs of the prime number theorem.